# XPS 9560 cannot install Ubuntu. ACPI Error / Empty Installation type / "unable to find a medium containing a live file system”

Tags: 16.04, usb, 17.10, xps

Dell XPS 15 9560, BIOS is up-to-date (Feb 18).
I'm trying ton install Ubuntu 16.04/17.10/18.04beta from USB thumb drive (SanDisk USB 3.0), but when the installation starts it gives errors:

[image]

ACPI Error Namespace llopup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND

Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
cannot disable (err = -32)

I tried different USB as well as different USB ports,
and also tried Ubuntu 17.10 as well but no luck.

I could proceed to “**Installation Type**” (but there is no partition) after `acpi=off` as kernel param but then it crashes when I try to select “+” or “Change”, so it seems like it does not help. But the partition is empty, so something is wrong.

[image]

After a struggle, it seems like I needed to change *Raid on* to *AHCI* for *SATA* setting, but after the change I still cannot reach the installation screen or it just freezes as error occurs `unable to find a medium containing a live file system` as shown below:

[image]

Ref:
http://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and finally worked!
with kernel params added `nouveau.modeset=0 acpi=off` after `quiet splash`.

After installation is done, I needed to start recovery mode
and do this.

`dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Answer (score 1):

A combination of these things might work for you:

- Change the boot mode to AHCI
- hit X at the GRUB bootloader screen and change `live splash` to `nomodeset`
- If it's a USB 3.0 USB make sure you use a USB 3.0 port
- If the USB 3.0 USB isn't working - try a USB 2.0 port
- If that still doesn't work - try a USB 2.0 key in a USB 2.0 port
- If you have no USB 2.0 ports try going into the BIOS and disabling USB 3.0 at the BIOS level
- If you can't disable USB 3.0 in BIOS then congratulations you're just as stuck as I am now

Comment: Changing live splash to nomodeset did the trick for me - thanks!